# How to get Parent data even if children are not present?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, entity-relationship

I would like to retrieve parent columns from a nested resource controller. If the nested controller has at least single row, I can easily retrieve the parent. But if there are no rows for a nested controller, how can I get the parent object?

To explain this:

```
/* I have two routes: */
Route::resource('articles', 'ArticleController');
Route::resource('articles.images', 'ArticleImageController');
```

ArticleImage model has this function:

```
public function article() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
    }
```

Here is how I get data:

```
/* www.site.com/articles/1/images */
public function index($id) {
        //
        $data['images'] = ArticleImage::where('article_id', $id);
        // to get parent data, I can call 
        $article = $data['images'][0]->article();
    }
```

The problem is, if there are no images. Then how can I get the parent article object? Because I want to show it's name on the images page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method using article id, not image id:

```
/* www.site.com/articles/1/images */
public function index($id) {
    //
    $data['images'] = ArticleImage::where('article_id', $id);
    // to get parent data, I can call 
    $article = $data['images'][0]->article();
}
```

So your Article model:

```
public function images() {
    // change the name according to your model
    return $this->hasMany('App\Images');
}
```

And how you retrieve images

```
/* www.site.com/articles/1/images */
public function index($id) {
    // Get the article
    $article = Article::with('images')->find($id);
    // Here is your article images
    $article->images;
}
```

Comment: hi @Iamzozo actually I am not talking about the Article controller but the Image controller. I know I can retrieve images under the article controller. But what I want is the opposite of what you shared above. I want to retrieve article object from Image controller when there are no images.

Comment: I know, this index function is in your **ImageController**, not in Article. Because you nesting the resource route, the first parameter will be the article id. This route: `articles/1/images` call your Image controller index method (as you set it), with the article id 1. This route: `articles/1/images/2` will call your `show` method: `show($article_id, $image_id)` in **ImageController**

Comment: I get it now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a crude workaround - instead of getting the `ArticleImage`, get the parent `Article` since that's what the `$id` is for and eager load the `images` relationship. That way you'll always have the parent article as `$article` even if there are no `images`.

```php
/* www.site.com/articles/1/images */
public function index($id) {
    $article = Article::with('images')->find($id);

    $data['images'] = $article->images;
    $data['article'] = $article;

    return view('my.view', $data);
}
```

You'll have access to `$article` in your view if you pass `$data` to it.

**UPDATE**

I realized this approach is almost identical to @Iamzozo's answer.